# Javascript detect browser scroll to the top?

Tags: javascript, scroll, browser

How do I modify the following code to detect scrolling to the top page instead.

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        alert(bottom);
    }
};
```

EDIT:

I am working on IE 10 for Windows Phone 8 BTW

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. Here's my code:

```
window.onscroll = function() {

    var body = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
    var document = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
    document = (document.clientHeight) ? document : body;

    if (document.scrollTop == 0) {
        alert("top");
    }        
};
```

Chek it running:

```js
window.onscroll = function(){

    var B = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
    var D = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
    D = (D.clientHeight)? D: B;
    
    if (D.scrollTop == 0){
        alert("top");
    }        
};
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

> **EXPLANATION OF HOW THIS CODE WORKS:**
>
> `window.onscroll` is the command to assign the [onscroll event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) to
> the `window` element.
>
> Now, as the `onscroll` event gets fired *when an element's scrollbar
> is being scrolled.*, the element will be  the `window` itself in this
> case.
>
> Now, the `function` will be called when the event is fired.
>
> In the function, we get the "document.body" to as en IE is the way to
> get it. After this, we get the documentElement, if there is a doctype.
>
> Then, this line, is the one that chooses between the document or the
> body if the `document.clientHeight` is informed. If it's informed, it
> will put document on variable document. If not, it will put the body
> itself.
> After this, it will check the scrollTop [property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp) in order to know
> if current scroll position is "at the top"

Comment: Would anyone be kind enough to explain how this code works? I'm struggling to understand it... :/

Comment: @AaronMatthews there you have it ;)

Comment: This answer from 2015 is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633515/470749

Answer (score 5):

`window.scrollY` is not cross-browser [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollY). On IE<9 you must check `document.body.scrollTop`, as no property of `window` will give you the current scroll position. Actually, `document.body.scrollTop` is what I use most  frequently, as in my experience it just works.

Comment: Sorry I am not very familiar with javascript. The following does not work  `window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
        alert("top");
    }
};`

http://jsfiddle.net/4gXN2/17/

Comment: You have a syntax (extra parentheses) stopping execution, try this updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/4gXN2/18/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.body.scrollTop == 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0) 
{
    alert("top");
}
```

worked for me

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this with only JS is the following example adding an event listener:

```
var el = document.getElementById('PUT_YOUR_TOP_ELEMENT_ID_HERE');
el.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    if (event.target.scrollTop === 0) {
        alert('Top of page detected');
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

its really simple:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  let scrollAmount = window.scrollY;
  console.clear()
  console.log(scrollAmount)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer gave me an error saying "document is undefined". So here is my solution.

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) == window.innerHeight) {
        alert(top);
    }
};
```

This checks if the innerHeight + pageYOffset = innerHeight. Which means you can also use:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if (window.pageYOffset == 0) {
        alert(top);
    }
};
```

Both work for me.