# Detecting webpage scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am trying to detect the scroll of a web page using JavaScript

I want to get an alert once only when the page is at top or not

```js
var top = true;
      
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      
      if (window.scrollY > 0 && top==true) {
        top = false;
       alert("not top");
      }else if (window.scrollY == 0 && top==false){
       top = true;
       alert("top");
      }     
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above code is not triggering alert at all !

Comment: See this answer please @fraizor https://stackoverflow.com/a/16433490/3617531

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is `top` is a javascript global variable which is conflicting with your variable. Your solution will work if you use another variable. If you just want an alert when the window is scrolled to the top then you can use the following solution -

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if(window.pageYOffset === 0) {
        alert("top");
    }
})
```

Comment: Good answers are more than just "this should work", they explain what the problem is and how the solution solves it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorry, I will be editing the answer. Thanks for pointing out.